# Gitlab Environment Variable not working when it's branch-specific

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I have a branch on GitLab, called "a-branch-123".

The project itself is a monorepo consistenting of multiple pipelines and child-pipelines.

Therefore it has multiple gitlab-ci.yml files.

If I set a variable called THREAT_LEVEL via Settings->CI/CD-> Variables and set the Environment scope to All(default), I'm able to easily make use of the variable in my yml files via simply saying $THREAT_LEVEL. The .yml prints out all the variables set via the "env" command.

However, because THREAT_LEVEL is something I want the developer to be able to change to varying values, on a branch by branch basis, I figured they'd be able to do this via creating a wildcard for Environment scope and setting it to "a-branch-123",.

When I do this, and start my pipeline, $THREAT_LEVEL isn't set to anything, and doesn't show when the pipeline does an "env" print-out.

Why is this?

[image]

Comment: "Environment Scope" is to scope variables to _environments_ -- NOT to scope variables to _branches_. A wildcard (`*`) can be used to match multiple environments -- but the pattern you've specified has no wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

The "Environment Scope" [setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/index.html#limit-the-environment-scope-of-a-cicd-variable) is to scope variables to *environments* -- NOT to scope variables to branches. Hence, the variable will only be available to jobs that declare an [`environment:` key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environment) with an environment name matching the specified scope.

A wildcard (`*`) can be used to match multiple environments -- but the pattern you've specified has no wildcard.

---

You can't scope variables to branches from the CI/CD variables settings, but if you want to declare variables on a per-branch basis, you can use `rules:variables:` either at the job or workflow level.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "abc-123"
      variables:
        THREAT_LEVEL: "$THREAT_LEVEL_ABC_123"
```

Comment: thanks for your response, in the example you've provided would you be setting THREAT_LEVEL with Environment Scope: All(default) then?

Comment: Because i'm not sure if that's relevant then - as it would already be set

Comment: @cien I would omit `THREAT_LEVEL` from settings altogether. You can set multiple variables by different names and control which one is in effect via `rules:variables:`

Comment: Like I said, when it's set to Environment scope: All(default), I can immediately access the variable by just doing $THREAT_LEVEL, I didn't need to do any variables: setting in the yml